# How to seed an user with a few claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application using EF Core 3.1.
How can I seed an user with a few claims? I was unable to find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method for seeding a super user you can tweak it to suit you

```
    private void SeedUsers(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
           //Check if it's already seeded
           if (userManager.FindByEmailAsync(_superUserDetails.Email).Result != null)
              return;

           //Create User
           var user = new AppUser
           {
              UserName = _superUserDetails.UserName,
              Email = _superUserDetails.Email,
              FirstName = "Clarke",
              LastName = "Kent"
           };
            
           //Set password
           var userResult = userManager.CreateAsync(user, _superUserDetails.Password).Result;
           if (!userResult.Succeeded)
              throw new SeedingException(userResult.Errors);

          //Add superUser  Claim
          var superUserClaim = new Claim("MyRoleClaimType", "SuperUser", ClaimValueTypes.String, "MyIssuer");
          var roleResult = userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, superUserClaim).Result;
          if (!roleResult.Succeeded)
             throw new SeedingException(roleResult.Errors);


        }//SeedUsers
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea to put this in the middleware?

Comment: I don't think so. It should only be run once on startup. Middleware would be run on every http request. So somewhere in your startup class is probably the best place